Start gnome wayland as another user and access shutdown options
After having used gdm to log as user1 under gnome wayland (on TTY2), I open a new VT TTY3, log in as user2, and run gnome-shell --wayland. This starts gnome shell on TTY3, as expected, and user2 (another person from my family) can now work on TTY3 while I am still logged in on TTY2. But the gnome shell instance on TTY3 has no “shutdown” option in the relevant menu, only log out. And log out does not work. So to shut down the computer, the second user has to switch back to TTY2 and shut down from there. Not convenient.
How can I start gnome wayland from the new TTY, bypassing gdm, but still having access to the usual gnome shut down menu? (Making “log out” work for user2, e.g. going back to the non graphical TTY2, would be a plus.)
I have tried to replace gnome-shell --wayland by gnome-shell --display-server --wayland (no change), dbus-run-session -- gnome-shell --display-server --wayland (gnome starts but then I cannot run anything from there), /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session /usr/bin/gnome-session (“unable to register display with display manager”), dbus-run-session /usr/libexec/gdm-wayland-session /usr/bin/gnome-session (similar reaction), gnome-session (nothing apparent happens), to no avail.
Also, any pointer to official documentation about which command is supposed to work and why would be most appreciated. I have found numerous suggestions on the web (all tried as indicated here above) but have no idea which ones are officially recommended.
(For the curious: the question stems from a desire to bypass gdm for user2 so as to, in the future, log in without having to type a password using systemd configuration.)
